# how to remove a variable from inside a function in R

Tags: r

i am trying to create a function in which i want to remove one of the variables passed to it.

now R works in annoying ways in that it copies the object instead of giving a reference.
(technically the copying only happens if you make a change... but meh...)

```
a=function(b){
  rm(b)
  # rm(b)
}
test=123
a(test) # will remove b, not test
# you can verify that by adding the 2nd rm(b)
```

i tried

```
a=function(b){
  rm(match.call()[[2]])
}
```

but that gives the error:

```
 Error in rm(match.call()[[3]]) : 
  ... must contain names or character strings
```

Comment: Make `rm` climb up the environment list. See `?rm`.

Comment: is it the ```pos``` argument? there is no example with that

Comment: Either `pos` or `envir`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Foo <- function(x){
  Sx <- deparse(substitute(x))
  rm(list=Sx,envir=sys.frame(-1))
}
##
Z <- 123
ls()
##
[1] "Foo" "Z" 
##
Foo(x=Z)
ls()
[1] "Foo"
```

Comment: TY! i had to change it cause i use S4 methods, and they first need to get through a generic function (the R language really sucks!) ```rm(list=deparse(substitute(other)),envir=sys.frame(-2))```

Answer (score 0):

similar to nrussell's answer, here's the line from `cgwtools::askrm` which does an arbitrary function call on the selected object:

```
call(fn, as.name(thenam)), envir = parent.frame(1))
```

(and, yes, I'm plugging my own toolkit here :-) )

Comment: +1 for the sameless plug, -10 for not using default R :P